# Using R doing map-matching of GPS data?

Tags: r, google-maps, dictionary, gps

Here is the thing.
I have a bunch of vehicles GPS data points, which consist of "timestamp, longitude, latitude, fuel consumption and distance" and the data is OSM(open street map) based. I want to match the data points to OSM, divide it by road type, so that I could get road type specific data in groups (e.g, highway group, local roadway group). Then I'll could calculate the fuel efficiency corresponding to different road type.

This is a project I'm currently doing. I'm wondering if R has any packages could handle this type of task?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/174515/115

Answer (score 1):

I have recently commented a similar question here on stackoverflow.

[R: How to identify a road type using GPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318880/r-how-to-identify-a-road-type-using-gps)
You need a package that wraps an API enabling "reverse geocoding" service. In detail you need a function that extracts extra information other than the the address. See package ggmap as suggested in the other thread for example. Not sure you can extract the detail you need.. Anyway it is worth a try.
Take a look at the package Nominatim (https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim) or geocodeHERE(https://github.com/corynissen/geocodeHERE) as well. And please inform us all about successes or failures :) Good luck